# Reading column from local database c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

This is a really simple question I am sure, so please bear with me. I have created a local database in visual studio 2010. I have created a table with columns `(c1,c2)`. I have also created a dataset using VS's wizard. This includes a `ListTableAdapter`. I am able to fill the database with values, but I am unable to get all of the rows in `c2`. Could anyone provide an example of getting a collection of rows from a specified column in c#? Please let me know if you need clarifying details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns don't have rows. You iterate through rows and choose the field.

e.g. something like

```
foreach(DataRow row in MyDataset.Table["TableName"].Rows)
{
  yield return row["FieldName"];
}
```

What type do you want and how do you want to deal with nulls will be a consideration.
Bear in mind that ColumnName in the table being fieldName in the datatable is a default.
Equally columns have native types, but a field in a DataRow is an object, which if null in the database will be set to DBNull.Value.